# Keep position of an overlapped div on an image with CSS

Tags: css

How I can overlap a `<div>` on an image and keep the same placement in responsive without having to play around the @media queries ?

For the moment the `<div>` cover the wall, but I want to keep the same look and feel in the screen is resized.

I thought playing with values in % can make the job but no.

Thanks a lot.

```html
<div class="inContextPhoto col-lg-6" style="position:relative">
  <p class="mt-2">Preview</p>
    <div style="display: block; position: absolute; margin-top: 22%; margin-left: 11%; height:37%; width: 71%; background: rgba(100,0,0,.2);"></div>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DkBmwZ3/ic-10-VM-Adobe-Stock-325313695.jpg" class="rounded" style="width: 100% !important">
</div>
```

Comment: Can’t see a problem. Behaves perfectly in Safari 17 and Chrome 119 on macOS 14.

Comment: Did you resize your window ? It when you resize that the red box will not cover perfectly the wall.

Comment: Yes, I did resize the browser window. The red box covers the wall perfectly at all sizes. Which browser are you using, on which operating system?